# Revision Info from CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

If I have a document with multiple revisions on CouchDB I can ask for a list of revisions like this:

```
localhost:5984/documents/document_guid?revs_info=true

{
    _id: document_guid,
    _rev: "2-rev_guid_B",
    _revs_info: [ {rev: "2-rev_guid_B", status: "available"}, {rev: "1-rev_guid_A", status: "available"} ],
    etc: "stuff"
}
```

And I can request a previous revision with the following request:

```
localhost:5984/documents/document_guid?rev=1-rev_guid_A

{
    _id: document_guid,
    _rev: "1-rev_guid_A",
    etc: "stuff in a previous life"
}
```

I was expecting to be able to do both at once, but it doesn't seem to work!

```
localhost:5984/documents/document_guid?rev=1-rev_guid_A&revs_info=true

// I wanted

{
    _id: document_guid,
    _rev: "1-rev_guid_A",
    _revs_info: [ {rev: "2-rev_guid_B", status: "available"}, {rev: "1-rev_guid_A", status: "available"} ],
    etc: "stuff in a previous life"
}

// I get

{
    _id: document_guid,
    _rev: "1-rev_guid_A",
    etc: "stuff in a previous life"
}
```

Does anyone know if what I want is possible, and if so, how I can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In CouchDB, it is considered one of the most common errors to try to use its "revisions" for a revision system.

"Revisions" are planned to be renamed "mvcc" to prevent this error. They should indeed be used only by the replicator and to detect concurrent updates.

If you need *real* revisions, you will have to implement them.

Comment: I've seen the same discussion pop up around the place, but is there a reason why I'd want to implement my own revisions system if I want an unchangeable audit trail of alterations to a document? I also don't want to be able to revert to a previous edition. I was under the assumption that it is this fact - that you can't do reverts - that makes CouchDB's 'revisions' poor for an actual revision system, and nothing else?

Comment: Because it was not meant to be a revision system: revisions are erased at compaction (which could happen at any time), they are not replicated, they cannot be used as easily as documents (as you noticed in your question).

Comment: Yes, couchdb isn't designed to manage revisions by user, although you can implement an update handler that is versioning your documents in a way you want it.

Comment: That's an interesting point - if I can't prevent compacting from occurring then I would loose my old revision data - definitely not a good thing! @sinm, I'm finding it hard to see writing an update handler to do versioning of documents as anything other than just replicating in-built functionality! Are there any other solid reasons why CouchDB shouldn't be used in this way?